# How to detect which processes are opened and closed with Python

Tags: python-3.x, process

I am trying to make a program in python to detect when some processes are opened or closed, and act according to a set rules (for example, backup a folder when a process is closed). I'd like to do it in the same way that inotify does it with files instead to be polling the process list every time. Also I want to make it work in Windows and Linux.

I have tried the polling way using psutil, but is quite slow when there are several processes (at least in Windows) and it also takes a lot of CPU, so is not the best way to make a process watcher.

```
import psutil
import time

while true:
  for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.name().lower() == PROCESSNAME:
      # tasks to do if a process is found
      ...

  time.sleep(5)
```

The above code iterates over all the running processes every 5 seconds. It takes more than 1 second to fully iterate all the processes and fully uses one core of my PC.

The "# tasks to do..." code block checks if the executable exists in a SQLite database placed on memory and print the returned data, but I have not added it here because it is not the problem.

It is possible to be notified on processes events in the same way that inotify API do it with filesystem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You wish to learn of process exit events.

Imagine that you were on a system that supports
[ptrace](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) or
[dtrace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dtrace).
You could readily subscribe to an event stream.
How might your current system produce similar events?

You are interested in specific FOO.EXE processes exiting.
For each of these programs, create a related FOO.BAT file
which produces "starting..." / "ending..." log events.
So the batch file will log, invoke the .exe, log again, and exit.

Now it's enough to `tail -f` the log file.
Or stat() its length and read at current offset.

---

It may also be helpful to RENAME FOO.EXE FOO1.EXE,
so that FOO unambiguously refers to the .BAT file.
(One could even produce a FOO.EXE executable
which logs and invokes FOO1.)

Comment: Hello, thank for your response. I'd like to do it in the less intrusive way, to avoid to have to edit every program link which sometimes is hard. That is why I want to detect the processes when they starts and ends. I want to make it that way mainly to backup non steam cloud games, emulators... which are hard to change their link or directly doesn't have it. I am trying python because can be programmed faster, but maybe I'll have to swich to C++ or another if I am not able to find the way to do it in python. For now my searches in Google are not helping, so maybe what I want is impossible.